# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\cos\frac {48} x}{\ln\cos\frac{1}{12x}}$ without using L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've seen some similar question, but none with $x\to\infty$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\cos\frac {48} x}{\ln\cos\frac{1}{12x}}$$
one of the ideas that i tried is, with $t=\frac{48}{x}$, changing the limit to:
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\ln\cos t}{\ln\cos\frac{t}{576}}$$
but it got me stuck pretty much there.

Thanks and sorry if it's basically a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this answer, we reach the solution using the well-known inequality $\color{#c00}{e^x≥x+1}$ .

---

We prove the following limit, which is *equivalent* to the original limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac {\ln \cos ax}{\ln \cos bx}=\frac {a^2}{b^2}$$

---

Using the substitution $x\longmapsto ±\ln x$ and applying the above inequality for $0<x<1$, we have :

$$
\begin{align}\ln x&≤x-1\\
\ln x&≥\frac {x-1}{x}\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}\frac {1}{\ln x}&≥\frac {1}{x-1}\\
\frac {1}{\ln x}&≤\frac {x}{x-1}
\end{align}
$$

---

The above inequalities lead to the following inequality :

$$
\begin{align}\cos bx\cdot\frac {1-\cos ax}{1-\cos bx}≤\frac{\ln\cos ax}{\ln\cos bx}≤\frac{1}{\cos ax}\cdot\frac {1-\cos ax}{1-\cos bx}\end{align}
$$

where $0<\cos ax<1$ and $0<\cos bx<1$ .

Since

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos ax}{1-\cos bx}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1-\cos ax}{(ax)^2}}{\frac{1-\cos bx}{(bx)^2}}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\end{align}
$$

Then, by [Squeeze theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) you are done .

Comment: very very good +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your reviewing .

Comment: Oh, for me it is a pleasure :-)